# GCD stop with cancellable_dispatch_after

Tags: ios, swift

Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) function they can utilize but once it's set up, these calls can not be easily cancelled.

How could we stop it such as a custom method "cancellable_dispatch_after"

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find a way to cancel asynchronous operations using GCD, you should use `DispatchWorkItem`. It allows you to do the following:

```
import Dispatch

let task = DispatchWorkItem {
    //Do some stuff
}
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: task)
task.cancel()
```

Obviously, you wouldn't do this exactly, but I believe it shows how to do what you want.

Hope this helps!